# How to shutdown a windows computer via a mac terminal

Tags: macos

Does anyone know how to shutdown a Windows 8 computer when connected via OS X terminal?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, this is possible via Samba's implementation of the net command.

```
net rpc shutdown -I <IP of Windows machine> -U <username on Windows machine>
```

You'll be prompted for a password and the Windows user obviously needs to have enough privileges to do a shutdown.

More information is available in the [Samba documentation](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/net.8.html).

To get Samba on your Mac, you can use a third party package manager such as [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) or [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)

Comment: I tried to shutdown a Windows 7 machine, but got an error after running the command and entering password:
`Could not initialise pipe \winreg. Error was NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND`

Answer (score -1):

You can shutdown Windows from Windows or Windows Server because they operate on Active Directory Domain Services (ADDS). This is a proprietary (i think) windows standard. Over the years the open source software community has written packages to allow Unix based OSes to communicate with ADDS. The project is named Samba.

That being said, this only works if you have a Windows Server running ADDS on the network. You could then configure Windows to connect to it, and your Mac to connect to it (through samba). Then with the proper permissions, you could issue a shutdown command to the Windows box from your Mac.

You can always search the internet for a program that allows you to run commands on the machine. In high school my friend wrote a Java program that would startup on a Win 7 machine and process his commands. The user can of course, simply terminate the program with a command of their own. As well, it would make the machine vulnerable to anyone else on the local network who knows about it.

Unfortunately, I think the answer is you can't. Unless you've got some expensive software on your (I'm assuming) home network.