# Shutdown Windows 7 PC from Mac terminal

Tags: windows-7, macos, shutdown, terminal.app

How can I shut down a Windows 7 PC remotely from a Macbook Pro, OSX El Capitan?

I saw [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/878070/how-to-shutdown-a-windows-computer-via-a-mac-terminal), where the most upvoted answer recommends using this command:

```
net rpc shutdown -I <IP of Windows machine> -U <username on Windows machine>
```

after installing samba.

I tried this, but got this error:

```
Could not initialise pipe \winreg. Error was NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
```

> [image: Could not initialise pipe \winreg. Error was NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND]
>
> **Note**: The username in the above image is the only user on the PC, apart from the Administrator user, but has Admin privileges. The ip address is the PC's IPv4 address (as per running `ipconfig` on the PC.) The PC's password has an exclamation mark (!) in it.

I think the error may be due to the targeted PC being Windows 7 as opposed to Windows 8.

## So, how can I shut down a Windows 7 PC remotely from a Mac?

Comment: Try this registry hack (http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/enable-mapping-to-hostnamec-share-on-windows-vista/) - should be same for Win 7... it might be related.

Comment: Ehm... the answer is not accepted, it is only _upvoted_... BTW [here](http://lifehacker.com/5275652/shut-down-your-windows-pc-remotely-from-linux) they suggest  `net rpc shutdown -I IPADDRESS -U USERNAME%PASSWORD` too, maybe forcing with `-f`.

Comment: I read now `The PC's password has an exclamation mark (!) `. Probably you need to escape it. Put it inside single quote `''` maybe so `-U USERNAME%'PASSWORD'` or variants. If you do not  the shell, bash I suppose, can start to substitute...

Comment: @Hastur I tried the command you just posted, escaping the password, but got the same error I had previously.

Comment: @BigChris What's that meant to do? Give me access remotely?

Comment: I think that [from] Vista the security permissions for RPC have been increased... if you turn off UAC on your Win 7 box and see if your command works (this will prove it's UAC related). See http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1309049

Comment: @BigChris Actually, editing that registry key fixed the problem! Would you like to re-phrase your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from HowToGeek.com there is a registry hack that can enable UAC elevation over the network when using a local user account of the remote machine.

The registry key is:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System

You will nedd to add a new `32-bit DWORD` value named `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy` and set the value to **1**.

Be warned, however, enabling this registry entry may make your remote computer susceptible to administrative access from other remote computers in a malicious way.

Source: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/enable-mapping-to-hostnamec-share-on-windows-vista/

Comment: `susceptible to administrative access from other remote computers` - any computer, or just those on the same LAN?

Comment: The `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy` registry change I've mentioned is basically allowing anyone who knows the username/password of an administrator account on your Windows 7 box to run remote commands and they'll be able to elevate any UAC command remotely... It sounds actually quite dangerous!

Comment: However, I am glad to know that you're only vulnerable to an attacker if they have the password.